# I filed my vector from a text file and it wont cout as one line. How can I do this?

Tags: c++, vector, io

Long story short I need my vector to cout as a single line without creating its own new lines for my program to work correctly. the text file i read into the vector was

```
laptop#a small computer that fits on your lap#
helmet#protective gear for your head#
couch#what I am sitting on#
cigarette#smoke these for nicotine#
binary#ones and zeros#
motorcycle#two wheeled motorized bike#
oj#orange juice#
test#this is a test#
```

filled the vector using the loop:

```
if(myFile.is_open())
{
    while(getline(myFile, line, '#'))
    {
        wordVec.push_back(line);
    }
    cout << "words added.\n";
}
```

and printed it using this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordVec.size(); i++)
{
    cout << wordVec[i];
}
```

and it outputs as such:

```
laptopa small computer that fits on your lap
helmetprotective gear for your head
couchwhat I am sitting on
cigarettesmoke these for nicotine
binaryones and zeros
motorcycletwo wheeled motorized bike
ojorange juice
testthis is a test
```

my program works if I manually input the words and add them to my data structure but if added from the vector which is filled via text file, half of the program doesnt work. before anyone says asks for a better description of the problem, all I need to know is how to fill the vector so that it will output as a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code `getline(myFile, line, '#')` reads everything up to end-of-file or the next '#' into `line` - that includes any newlines.  So, as you read text file content...

```
laptop#a small computer that fits on your lap#
helmet#protective gear for your head#
```

...which you could also think of as...

```
"laptop#a small computer that fits on your lap#\nhelmet#protective gear for your head#"
```

...`line` takes on successive values...

```
"laptop"
"a small computer that fits on your lap"
"\nhelmet"
...etc....
```

Note the newline in `"\nhelmet"`.

There are many ways to avoid or correct this, such as...

```
while ((myFile >> std::skipws) and getline(myFile, line, '#'))
    ...
```

...or...

```
if (not line.empty() and line[0] == '\n')
    line.erase(0, 1);
```

...or (as Barry suggests in comments)...

```
while (getline(myFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string field;
    while (getline(iss, field, '#'))
        ...
}
```

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: true - and often desirable anyway so you can count line numbers for diagnostic messages....

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet so how could I turn laptop#a small computer that fits on your lap into string1 = laptop and string2 = a small computer that fits on your lap. the two suggestions you posted did not work.

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit What do you mean "did not work" - what happened?  FWIW, if you got error messages about `and` and `not`, it means you're not using a C++ Standard-compliant compiler (perhaps you're using Microsoft's sorry excuse?): if so, you can use `&&` and `!` respectively instead, or search MS docs for the command line options to enable `and` and `not`.

Comment: I did use && and ! because this is indeed VS2012

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit: you're not an easy Wabbit to help ;-P; *after* you used those, did it start working, or are you saying it didn't work even with those?  If the latter, what actually happened?  Compile error (and if so which)?  Wrong output (and if so what output)? ...

Comment: it didnt work after I implemented either one. got error message upon program launch. I implemented them in the correct place with the correct code and got a run time error. I dont remember exactly what it was but it crashed before my first debugging cout that said words had been added. I made it work with the suggested code though

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit: oh well, not enough info to troubleshoot, but good that you're past this hurdle and back coding away....   Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(getline(myFile, line, '#'))
```

Here, you told `std::getline` to use the '#' character instead of a newline, `'\n'`, as a delimiter.

So, this simply means that `std::getline` will no longer think there's anything special about `'\n'`. It's just another character that `std::getline`() will keep reading, looking for the next `#`.

So, you end up reading newline characters into your individual strings, and then outputing them to `std::cout`, as part of the strings you've printed.